# Web API Post object become null when its content around 1 GB or more

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Everything is working as expected when content length around 600MB, when it get closer to 1GB or above then entity become null at Web API.

Here is MVC client code, which invoking the Web API:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()))
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_serviceRootUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    return await client.PostAsJsonAsync(controlActionPath, entityObject);
}
```

Here is the web API code:

```
[Route("Upload")]
[HttpPost]
public void Upload(DocumentDto entity)
{
    var dbEntity = new DocumentDto
    {
        AddBy = entity.AddBy,
        AddOn = DateTime.Now
    };           
}
```

Here is the code of DocumentDto class:

```
public class DocumentDto
{
    public int DocumentSeqId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    public int AddBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddOn { get; set; }
}
```

Web.config is:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="600" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Please let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Comment: It would be better design to not send the unstructured data as a part of your json but on a separate request and stream it (both writing and reading). I would also not advise you to save it to the DB as databases are designed to work best with structured data. Instead consider writing it to the file system with a pointer to the file in the database. If you must save it to the DB  there might also be the possibility of writing as a stream but it depends on the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: @lgor - We are using mogodb to store the file content.

Comment: I think you mean mo**n**godb? I am not sure if there is a good way to stream unstructured content into mongodb, you would have to check. What you do not want though is working with the entire byte array at once.